# How can i get the custom response body from an API Post request with AWS API gateway from React Native application?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, react-native, httprequest, aws-api-gateway

I have an API Setup in API Gateway with 2 routes currently: Login and Register which are both attached to AWS Lambdas to perform operations on a DynamoDB Table.

When I perform a Post Request on Postman, I can see my custom response Body in the body of the response i get back. I'm using this to get back a jwt token hence the need for custom body.
[image: Postman Success Response]

However, in my React Native code:
[image: ReactNative Request Code]

I get a correct status code in the response of 200 but if i log out response.body i get "undefined"...
Edit: There is also no sign of the jwt token under any other name in the response when thats logged out as a whole too.

any help would be appreciated! Thanks

EDIT: EXTRA PHOTOS
[image: Full Request, URL hidden]
[image: Response with some things scribbled out]

Comment: You usually need to await for response.json()

Comment: @ThibaultCapelli I have done this just hiding the URL for the request :)

Comment: Could you please write all the code and replace your url by <URL> or whatever ? Cause it's just looks like response is the result of a fetch in your snippet

Comment: @ThibaultCapelli Added 2 extra photos, one showing request and one showing the response :)

Comment: So I was right. See my first comment.

Comment: const json = await response.json();

Comment: console.log(JSON.stringify(json));

Comment: ah  I see sorry - i'm still getting the same result though.

Comment: In your case it's maybe : const token = await response.text();

Comment: Still undefined unfortunately!

Comment: Ok so last try xD. Try const token = await response.blob();

Comment: Doesn't seem to exist in there either ;( @ThibaultCapelli maybe i need to set up a mapping in AWS integration but i'd have thought it would be fine as is if postman is picking up on it already

Comment: I think your request is okay. I'm actually surprised that: const token = await response.text() does not work cause you selected "Text" in your Postman and it is working. Could you please update your example with this code to show me?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251637/discussion-between-hbridges-and-thibault-capelli).

Answer (score 0):

Had to use
`await for response.text()`
to get the desired data out of the response, not just a single await on the whole response. Solved by @ThibaultCapelli